# Temporarily mount Windows share via cmd line? (Ubuntu 11.04)

Tags: ubuntu, samba, ubuntu-11.04, smb, cifs

What is a simple way to (temporarily) mount a windows share from within Ubuntu 11.04 via the command line?

Basically, I'd like the path `/home/myuser/windowsbox` to map to a windows share.  (Need to supply user/pass/domain)

Most of the tutorials I can find use fstab for a permanent mapping.  The GUI options do not let me specify a local path for the mounting.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `mount -t cifs` to do it from command line. Consult manpage for mount to learn about additional options like user/password/explicit filename encoding/file ownership etc. You would unmount it using `umount /home/myuser/windowsbox`

In particular see the `uid`/`gid` options. This will let normal users access the share.

There's also `smbfs` as mount type but please don't use it since it's being obsoleted by `cifs`.

Answer (score 3):

Open a command line and enter the following.

```
smbmount //MYWINBOX/MYSHARE /mnt/winstuff -o username=domain//username
```

From here you should be able to enter your password and mount your volume.

Comment: On my machine I get the error: `mount.cifs: permission denied: no match for /home/myuser/windowsbox found in /etc/fstab`

Answer (score 1):

What is the name of your Windows share that you're trying to map?  This is how I've done temporary mapping (substitute `//mywinbox/myshare` with the network path to the widows share you want to map and  with the username credentials to connect to your Windows box):

```
sudo mount -t cifs //mywinbox/myshare /home/myuser/windowsbox -o username=<username>
```

It would probably be recommended that you house your mappings in a more established location such as `/mnt/windowsbox` then perhaps create a symlink in the `/home/myuser` directory.  Just a thought for consistency.